# Get the number of spaces characters in a string?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, wc

How can I check how many white spaces (' ', `\t`) there are in the first line of a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683443/linux-counting-spaces-and-other-characters-in-file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A straightforward way would be to select just the first line, drop
non-witespace characters from it, and count how many characters are
left:

```
head -n 1 | tr -cd ' \t' | wc -c
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use GNU sed to replace the `head|tr` combo (here assuming POSIXLY_CORRECT is not in the environment):

```
sed '1s/[^ \t]//g' |wc -c
```

**Note:** sed will always print out a newline, so **the count you'll will include the newline itself.**  *How this works*: In sed, you can give the `s///` command an address range, which here is just the first line. Globally replace any non-whitespace with nul and output the result to `wc` which counts characters.

It's possible, but ugly, to figure out a pure-sed version which does the counting.

A perl version is also simple enough:

```
perl -lne 's/[^ \t]//g;print length($_);last'
```

The principle is the same. The `-l` option outputs a trailing newline. The `-n` option wraps the script in a giant while-readline loop. And `last` terminates that loop.

Stéphane's `awk` solution reminded me you can do that also with perl:

```
perl -lne 'print s/[[:space:]]]//g;last'
```

Or replace it with `[[:blank:]]` to include the newline and other non-printing characters.

Comment: Since you're calling `q` anyway the _address range_ is not necessary.

Comment: Removed the `q`

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print gsub("[ \t]",""); exit}' < file
```

Or to count any blank (horizontal spacing characters), not just space and tab:

```
awk '{print gsub("[[:blank:]]",""); exit}' < file
```

Answer (score 1):

*(works with most shells)*:

```
IFS=; <file \                       
read -r IFS                         # read 1 line into $IFS
set -- $IFS                         # split while eliding $IFS whitespace
echo "$((${#IFS}-$#))"              # $IFS len less $IFS field count
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32498/discussion-on-answer-by-mikeserv-how-can-i-get-the-number-of-spaces-characters-i).

Comment: @BinaryZebra - nah. it wasnt very good. it was too complicated.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - i didnt intend it to be impolite, and i sent that before i found you in chat.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nE '$n = tr/ / /; say $n; exit' file
```

Comment: Shorter one `perl -nE 'say tr/ \t//; exit'`